# Redirect if URL contains word

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have this script and it's working well, but it redirects to Google if the URL is this:

http://example.com/test/examples

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("/test") > -1) {
    window.location.href="http://google.hu";
}
```

I don't want to redirect if I have words after /test/.

So I need this:

http://example.com/test/examples  --> don't redirect

http://example.com/test ---> redirect

How can I do it with jQuery?

Comment: It's better to do redirects on the server; the client does not always support JavaScript or client-based redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to check if the url ends with test/

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.search(/test\/$/) >= 0) {
    alert("Do redirect!");   
}
```

or
    url.search(/test$/)
if you want to see if it ends with test